# Ansible - Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a problem trying to ping to machines using ansible,  1 is fedora 35 the 2nd is ubuntu 21.
when I run

```
ansible all -i inventory -m ping -u salam -k
```

I get the following warnings

> [WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host
> myubuntuIP: unexpected output from Python interpreter discovery
> [WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [myubuntuIP]. Use
> ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
> [WARNING]: scp transfer
> mechanism failed on [myubuntuIP]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed
> information myubuntuIP | SUCCESS => {
> "ansible_facts": {
> "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
> },
> "changed": false,
> "ping": "pong" }
> [WARNING]: Platform unknown on host myfedoraIP is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future
> installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of
> that path. See
> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.14/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html
> for more information. myfedoraIP | SUCCESS => {
> "ansible_facts": {
> "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
> },
> "changed": false,
> "ping": "pong"

when I do

```
which python3
```

on both machines, I get 2 different paths as follows

> /usr/bin/python3  for fedora box /bin/python3      for ubuntu box

I understand from 1 thread here that we should indicate the path of python in ansible.cfg file, Can I indicate 2 different paths in the ansible.cfg? If yes how? and why ansible is **not able** to find the python path?

Answer (score 1):

First, the error on your Ubuntu system appears unrelated to this question; it says:

```
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [myubuntuIP]
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [myubuntuIP]
```

I suspect to diagnose that issue you'll need to follow the instructions in the error message, set `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1`, and if the cause isn't immediately obvious open a new question here for that particular issue.

---

> I  understand from 1 thread here that we should indicate the path of python in ansible.cfg file, Can I indicate 2 different paths in the ansible.cfg? If yes how?

You don't set this in your `ansible.cfg` (unless you really do want a single setting for all your hosts); you set this in your Ansible inventory or in your `host_vars` or `group_vars` directory. For example, to set this on a specific host in your inventory, you might do something like this:

```
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    host2:
    host3:
```

You could accomplish the same thing by placing:

```
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

In `host_vars/host1.yaml`.

If the same configuration applies to more than one host, you can group them and then apply the setting as a group variable. For example, to apply the setting only to a subset of your hosts:

```
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
  children:
    fedora_hosts:
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      hosts:
        host2:
        host3:
```

Or to apply it globally:

```
all:
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
    host3:
```

> And why ansible is not able to find the python path?

That's not what the warning is telling you -- it **was** able to find the Python path (`/usr/bin/python`), but "future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path" (because `/usr/bin/python`, depending on your distribution, could actually be python 2 instead of python 3, etc).

Comment: One last thing, how do use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1? on command line or somewhere in a file because I tried on command line it did not work.

Comment: That direction is telling you to set an environment variable, which you can do by preceding the command with the variable assignment (`ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible-playbook ...`) or by setting it using the `export` command (`export ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1`).

Comment: OK thanks, so I cant group hosts in yaml in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between your two comments. Setting `ANSIBLE_DEBUG` does not impact your ability to create host groups in your inventory. You can of course group hosts exactly as I have demonstrated in this answer.